# How to transform HTML table to PDF

Tags: itext

I try to create a pdf out of a html using iText:

```
String html= "<table style=\";border: 2px solid black\">"
+ "<tr>"
+  "<td>Column 1</td>"
+  "<td style=\";border: 1px solid red; width: 80mm\";>Column 2</td>"
+ "</tr>"
+ "</table>";

Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("htmlFahrplan.pdf"));
pdfWriter.setLinearPageMode();
pdfWriter.setFullCompression();

document.addCreationDate();
document.open();

HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(html));
document.close();

pdfWriter.close();
```

But the generated pdf has no style settings: There is no border and
the column width is the same for every column!

Does anyone has any idea how to transform this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As a sidenote, HTMLWorker has been deprecated long ago and is not supported anymore. You should use [XMLWorker](http://www.itextpdf.com/product/xml_worker) instead.

Comment: You're right. XMLWorker does solve the problem. Thanks.